# Seeding a postgreSQL DB table using a large json file in Knex/Node

Tags: json, postgresql, knex.js, seed

I am trying to seed my database with a large JSON file. Passing the entire JSON was just producing errors probably due to memory issues. It works fine when I break the JSON up into smaller files however. I was investigating a way to read the JSON as a stream using the stream-json package to avoid having to split the JSON up into multiple files. But I have no idea how to incorporate this into the seed file. Or is there any other way to do this? Thanks

Here is what the code was looking like producing the error

```js
const { getAirports } = require('../helpers')
// const { getCountries } = require('../helpers')

exports.seed = async function (knex) {
  const airportList = await getAirports()
  return knex('airport')
    .del()
    .then(function () {
      return knex('airport').insert(airportList)
    })
}
```

then the helper function

```js
const airportArray = require('./smallairport.json')

async function getAirports() {
  try {
    const countryList = await getCountries()
    const formatted = airportArray.map(
      ({ name, iata, icao, city, country, state, lat, lon, elevation, tz }) => {
        const countryDetails = countryList.find(({ code }) => code === country)

        return {
          name,
          iata,
          icao,
          city,
          country: countryDetails.name,
          state,
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lon,
          timezone: tz,
          elevation
        }
      }
    )
    return formatted
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: What memory issues? On the server parsing the file, or were the errors coming from the database? How big is the file? Could you write a script to do connet to the DB and do it locally? More details please

Comment: I wasn't able to read the console error messages because it was just becoming a sea of red. The database is running on localhost and I was running the seed file locally as well.
There seems to be nothing wrong with the connection or data structure because it is processing fine if I split the JSON into a file not exceeding about 70,000 lines.